# Finding mixed case using RegExp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find 'PM' or 'P.M.' in input string as ignore case.
But this is not working...

```
const pmRex = new RegExp('PM|P\.M\.', 'gi');

console.log(pmRex.exec('PM'));
console.log(pmRex.exec('Pm'));
console.log(pmRex.exec('pm'));
console.log(pmRex.exec('P.M.'));
console.log(pmRex.exec('P.m.'));
console.log(pmRex.exec('p.m.'));
console.log(pmRex.exec('p.M.'));
console.log(pmRex.exec('p.m'));
```

result:

```
[ 'PM', index: 0, input: 'PM' ]
null
[ 'pm', index: 0, input: 'pm' ]
null
[ 'P.m.', index: 0, input: 'P.m.' ]
null
[ 'p.M.', index: 0, input: 'p.M.' ]
null
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches

Comment: Is expected result `Boolean` or matched string?

Comment: try changing the order of your `exec` - you'll see every second output is always null - check `exec` documentation to find out why

Comment: In addition to the `.exec()` issue, your regex is incorrect. If you are creating a regex from a string literal, you have to remember that backslashes need to be escaped in string literals, so use `new RegExp('PM|P\\.M\\.', 'gi')`. It's easier to use a regex literal: `/PM|P\.M\./gi`.

Comment: @guest271314 That's just testing code. I want to get the string.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for answering this! :)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you for answering about string literal. I will remember that! :)

Comment: @SeunghunKim You can substitute using `.match()` for `.exec()` to get array of matched strings

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to remove the `g` flag if you've no intention of actually using it

```js
const pmRex = /PM|P\.M\./i;

console.log('PM', pmRex.test('PM'));
console.log('Pm', pmRex.test('Pm'));
console.log('pm', pmRex.test('pm'));
console.log('P.M.', pmRex.test('P.M.'));
console.log('P.m.', pmRex.test('P.m.'));
console.log('p.m.', pmRex.test('p.m.'));
console.log('p.M.', pmRex.test('p.M.'));
console.log('p.m', pmRex.test('p.m'));
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches)...

> If your regular expression uses the `"g"` flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property

---

Otherwise, in order to execute `exec` or `test` repeatedly on different strings with a global flag, you need to reset the `lastIndex` property

```js
const pmRex = /PM|P\.M\./gi;

console.log('PM', pmRex.test('PM'));
pmRex.lastIndex = 0;

console.log('Pm', pmRex.test('Pm'));
pmRex.lastIndex = 0;

console.log('pm', pmRex.test('pm'));
pmRex.lastIndex = 0;

console.log('P.M.', pmRex.test('P.M.'));
pmRex.lastIndex = 0;

console.log('P.m.', pmRex.test('P.m.'));
pmRex.lastIndex = 0;

console.log('p.m.', pmRex.test('p.m.'));
pmRex.lastIndex = 0;

console.log('p.M.', pmRex.test('p.M.'));
pmRex.lastIndex = 0;

console.log('p.m', pmRex.test('p.m'));
```